# При нажатии на родительский элемент событие должен срабатывать только на родительский

Tags: jquery

Как делать так, чтобы при нажатии на родительский элемент событие срабатывала только на родительский элемент, а дочерний элемент не трогать.
Пример кода:

```
<body>
<div id="sel">Hello world!</div>
</body>

<script>
jQuery("body").on("click", function(){alert("Hello world!")})
</script>
```

Как делать так, чтобы при клике на элемент `body` появился `alert`, а при клике на дочерний элемент `sel` чтобы ничего не было? В моем случае и `body` и `sel` одинаково работают, а `:not(.sel)` не помогает.

Comment: думаю, надо почитать про всплытие и перехват событий JS

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать проверку на целевой элемент `event.target`. Это единственный оптимальный вариант который я знаю.

Небольшое пояснение, Мы вешаем событие на определенный элемент, прим. `body`. Когда событие происходит на каком то элементе, то браузер пробегается от корня к этому элементу и каждому по пути говорит что событие произошло, потом тоже самое обратно. Чтобы разработчик мог узнать конкретный элемент в коллбэк события передается параметр `target` который указывает на непосредственно элемент на котором произошло это событие.

`:not(.sel)` – это немного в другую сторону, это селектор для элементов, он у вас собственно и выбирает элемент `body`.

```js
var body = document.body;

body.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
  if ( e.target === body ) {
    alert('Hello world');
  }
});
```

```css
body, html {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button>No event</button>
```